# MVC3: Value of Caching for @Html.Hidden

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This is a question being asked out of curiosity, not because there's a problem I've encountered that I can't solve.

In MVC3 (and probably earlier versions, too) I frequently encounter problems using @Html.Hidden and @Html.HiddenFor, all of which derive from the "behind the scenes" caching that the helper methods utilize. For those not familiar with it, re-executing a partial view that uses those helpers will grab values from a cache, even if you supply new values to the method call. I'm not too clear on just when that happens, but I know it does, and have seen it documented as an issue to be aware of online.

I'm wondering what the value of this caching is. At least in the way I use hidden fields, the values are different on every view execution. Given that usage pattern, the caching gets in the way more frequently than it helps.

In what kinds of scenarios does the caching add value?

Comment: Have a read of [this](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Apr/20/ASPNET-MVC-Postbacks-and-HtmlHelper-Controls-ignoring-Model-Changes) - does this sound like the issue you describe?  Have a look under the heading 'What should the behavior be?' Rick describes the reasoning behind the behvaiour.

Comment: Perfect, thanx! I can see why the default behavior is by design. It has nothing to do with caching. Instead, it's so that erroneous values can be retained.